# Can we provide data to jasper in paginated fashion?

Tags: jasper-reports

I would like to provide data to jasper in paginated way to avoid OutOfMemory errors. I understand that there is Virtualizer concept in Jasper. But Virtualizers, as I understand, are useful only while filling the reports, which means that I provide complete set of say 10,000 objects to Jasper and then it uses virtualizers to fill the data and write to files to avoid OOM.
What I am interested in knowing is whether I can provide query 1000 records at a time and provide this to Jasper and fill it in loop(of 10 times, 10*100).

In our case, we do not use query directly in report as we need to decorate the object before we want to export it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a class that extends [`JRDataSource`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDataSource.html) that handles the logic you want. Basically you will paginate it yourself.

If you are querying a database to get your data, then you can use a paginated query to get the data for 1000 rows at a time. Then decorate the data. When next is called after the 1000th item is called, then you do the query again for the next 1000.

As far as I know there is not a ready made solution for this as part of the library.